# Apply a particular theme to a drawable

Tags: android

As stated in the title, I'd like to be able to programmatically apply a theme to a drawable resource.

I have an XML drawable resource which reference colors using `?attr/logoColorPrimary`. If I define the colors in the main them, it works correctly and the drawable is displayed with the correct color.

Now I'd like to use that same drawable resource elsewhere in my application, but using different colors. Is there a way I can programmatically apply a different theme to that drawable? Of course, I tried to use the `style` XML attribute on the `AppCompatImageView` that drawable. But, as it turns out, locally redifining the styl on the view does not override the attributes that are passed down to the drawable.

Comment: have you tried using `android:theme` XML attribute?

Comment: Oh... That works... Thanks!
Can you propose it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [getDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/res/ResourcesCompat#getDrawable(android.content.res.Resources,%20int,%20android.content.res.Resources.Theme)) there is a param for the theme, something like

```
val yourTheme = ContextThemeWrapper(baseContext, R.style.AppTheme).theme
ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.your_drawable, yourTheme)
```

Comment: You specified 'programatically' in your answer so thought id give you that, no worries